# Galaxy S II via Freebox server to TV

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

Any idea how can I connect my Samsung Galaxy S II to Freebox server? I have no idea how to set up wifi connection between them. Please note that I want to connect my phone to Freebox server as described here, I just want to get pictures straight off of my phone onto the Freebox server to TV.

Comment: what's a "Freebox"? From a quick google search, you could be referring to a certain [French ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebox) or to an music [Jukebox](http://www.freeboxjukebox.com/) software.

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking about Free as the french ISP...

The freebox is an ADSL modem that the french ISP Free provides to his client. It includes a modem / nas / tv and other funny stuff... It provides also multimedia features like photo gallery and video player [1](http://www.free.fr/adsl/multimedia.html)

It presents a nas system accessible thru FTP, and other protocole. To answer to your question, you can install a **FTP client on your mobile** and connect directly to your server to put your photos. But the prerequisite is a configured server...

To go further and help you to configure all stuff, we need to know which version of freebox do you have, v5 or v6 (HD)

You can find a really good tutorial in french on this page: [2](http://www.craym.eu/tutoriels/ftp/freebox-revolution-ftp-filezilla.html#configurer)

---

**An extract of configuration needed for the HD version.**

You need to configure your freebox server if it's not already done via the following site: mafreebox.freebox.fr/

The freebox server is accessible thru the following parameters / put it into your android ftp client:

- address : mafreebox.freebox.fr
- login : freebox
- password configured one on : mafreebox.freebox.fr